# Integrating SYGIC in Mono for Android

Tags: c#, monodevelop, xamarin.android

Could anyone help me on how to integrate Sygic SDK in Mono for Android.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that SDK, but in looking quickly at [their site](http://www.sygic.com/en/business%3asdk) it looks like they offer an Android version of the SDK, which I'm guessing comes in the form of a .jar file. If that's the case, Mono for Android provides the ability to create bindings for Java libraries that you can access in your applications via C#, so I would suggest giving that a shot. There is some good documentation [available here](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Binding_a_Java_Library_%28.jar%29) on how to get started creating a binding project.